# Active MQ security and scalability

Tags: android, activemq-classic

I've currently setup an Android and iOS app to use ActiveMQ MQTT for my message relays. It all works fine but I have the following questions that I would be grateful if anyone could help with:

1) As I understand, all clients need to keep an open TCP connection to the MQ server (for obvious reasons) and subscribe to topics and when a topic is published, the subscribed clients get a notification. If the number of clients is in the millions, it would mean millions of active open TCP connections. What are the ramifications of such number of open connections to a server? Is there a better way to handle the situation? Would you recommend instead to connect say once a minute or so, query for the "State of the world" (i.e. the latest unread messages) and disconnecting the clients? or am I being paranoid and millions of open TCP connections is fine?

2) On the subject of security, I understand that I can use SSL which is great but I still don't understand how to prevent a third party from subscribing to all topics (or even individual topics)? As far as I understand, clients need to connect to a server and subscribe to a topic but what would prevent a third party application from doing the same? How would I prevent such a thing and make sure that only clients from my app are able to connect and subscribe to their own topics?

Many thanks in advance for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you do reconnect , you will need to make sure your clients create durable subscriptions.  If not, you miss out on anything that was published between connections.  This can also be a scalability issue that you will need to consider.  With millions of connections you will want to consider using a cluster, or some sort of topology that supports load balancing, regardless of approach you take.  Constantly reconnecting clients can cause unexpected overhead as well as the Broker(s) attempt to keep up with everything that is coming and going.  A big part of your decision will be based on your hardware as well as with any server.

This only scratches the surface of topologies, but [here is a good starting point.](http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html)

**Edit:**  Added information to try to address your concerns on millions of connections that I meant to add the first go.

2. You can set up role based security via authentication plug-ins within ActiveMQ.  Each role/group can be set up with a pattern using wild cards to allow access to a specific topic tree.

[See this page for more details on setting this up.](http://activemq.apache.org/security.html)

[Here is another](http://rijware.com/securing-mqtt-on-apache-activemq/) site with good information that should answer your questions on how to and how it works.